# Error while loading URL through class WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

Error while loading URL. I have also provided all the required permission.
 Console -> Error: -6 net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED.

```
 webview.setListener(this, this)
    webview.setDownloadListener(this)
    webview.run {
        setMixedContentAllowed(true)
        setGeolocationEnabled(true)
        setCookiesEnabled(true)
        setThirdPartyCookiesEnabled(true)
    }

    with(webview.settings) {
        javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        domStorageEnabled = true
        javaScriptEnabled = true
        userAgentString = "Android WebView"
        allowFileAccess = true
        allowContentAccess = true
        allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true
        allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true
    }
    webview.clearCache(true);
    webview.clearHistory();
    webview.reload();
    //load url
    webview.loadUrl(url)
```

Comment: there is a problem with your server/your internet connection.

Comment: can you show the code

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko there is no problem while accessing through the browser.

Comment: @ZeeshanKhan I have added a few lines of code. Please give a look.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any kind of antivirus like Baidu? if you're using so I fond this solution for you [please translate this link into english](http://bbs.51cto.com/thread-1462339-1.html)  according to this

"Dear, the first time to post for help, usually Baidu, this time no Baidu, ask for help ~

part of the phone Android client https-webview prompt ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED, has Baidu, unresolved.

Access to the https page does not work, but access to the https service is normal 
(previously Android 6.0 can not access the https service, and later added information such as ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA" in the tomcat configuration).

When debugging, when listening to webview-onrecievederr, it returns ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED to

listen to onrecievedsslerr. It seems that it is not reflected, and the log here is not printed. . 
OnReceivedSslError inside the code is as follows: 
handler.proceed (); / / accept all the website's certificate 
and print log information, but when running, the log information is not printed

temporarily known phone models such as OPPO R9, Samsung S6, Huawei mate 8.

When the development environment is debugged (the code has not been changed), the mobile phone in this situation occurs in the production environment, but the relevant https-webview is opened in the development environment.

Put the production environment's tomcat configuration file server.xml into the development environment to run debugging, also normal.

Because Baidu said that it may be a port problem, then the development environment will configure tomcat ssl-port to 8443 or 9010 debugging, also normal.

The production environment has done apache load balancing (tomcat is deployed on 4 hosts respectively), and the external network https-9010 corresponds to https-8443 of the intranet.

Please give the big god a direction."

Answer (score 0):

There is some issues with webview google security and ssl, Try to use https instead of http, if the url http only you can ignore SSL certificate errors.to ignore do a workaround by overriding onReceivedSslError and remove  super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            // DOT CALL SUPER METHOD
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        }
    });
```

And to solve google security

```
setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Full code will be like this :

```
webView.enableJavaScript();
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {

        }
    });
```

To see the issue visit this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36907478#c15)